# python solution for parallelizing calls to non-pickleable 3rd party method?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

This is a somewhat general question without a specific code example. I'm trying to parallelize calls of a method from a 3rd party library. Using multiprocessing.Pool would be exactly what I want, but it fails because the method isn't pickle-able. Using something like twisted would be way overkill.

The individual calls are independent and the program can block waiting for the calls as a whole to finish. I do need to pass a few parameters in to the parallelized calls, which can be done with a list of dicts. So I need to achieve the equivalent of

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(count)
p.map(my_wrapper_around_some_3rd_party_method, my_list_of_dicts)
```

when the 3rd party method isn't pickle-able.

Is there an obvious python idiom or pattern I should be looking at?

Comment: Maybe you should figure out why the method isn't pickled. Is it dynamically generated? If so you'll need to do the same setup in subprocesses to make sure the method exists.

Comment: Yep, this led me to figure out how to make things work. I had to put a method at the top level in the module and do some object reconstruction therein so it would work properly when called in subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help: 
https://khinsen.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/teaching-parallel-computing-in-python/

In his case, numpy.sqrt() isn't picklable and he calls it in a local function which he gives to map.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `multiprocess`, which is a fork of `multiprocessing` that is able to pickle most python objects.

```
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> 
>>> pool = mp.Pool()
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pool.map(np.sqrt, range(4)) 
[0.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772]
>>> pool.map(lambda x: x**2, range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

I'm the author, and you can get it here: https://github.com/uqfoundation or using `pip install`.